Quickly putting something to the power of 100 without a calculator (Shortcuts)
For some probability questions,
I was wondering if anyone knew of any tricks on how to do do the following;
let's say we have a fraction of 49/50 and we want to put this to the power of 100 quickly without using a calculator, what would you suggest? Or how would you estimate the solution?
EDIT:
Example of a probability question for which this can be relevant;

Assume you have a group of slot machines, and you know the group of slot machines pay out 100 times. Every payout is randomly distributed to one of 50 users. What is the probability that a given user will not recieve a payout? Assume that the events are random and independent from each other and that all users have an equal probability of recieving or not recieving a payout.



Anwser; 49/50^100. Since for a given user not to recieve the payout the payout has to go to one of the 49 other users, and this has to be repeated 100 times.


Now why not use a calculator you may ask?
In some cases using mental math may be faster than using a calculator, and for timed tests, and job interviews you may be required not to use an calculator to estimate the anwser.
Kind regards, Julien.

You can use the following limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n} =e^{-1}
$$
because the equation you wish to approximate is in a similar form:
$$
\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{50}\right)^{50}\right]^{2}
\approx e^{-2} \approx 0.1353
$$
although one can argue that to compute $e^{-2}$, you still need a calculator.

It helps if you know a few factorials & subfactorials. Eg, $1/e\approx(!5)/(5!)=44/120=11/30$, which is easy to square & divide.

I appreciate the anwser and comment! It definitly seems like a good shortcut for approximation in this case. Pherhaps also memorizing e to negative powers may help. If they ask for a probability that is e to the power of -5 or beyond. Then I know the probability will be less than 1%. Likewise if it's power is in between -1 and -2, I can estimate it as being somewhere in between 36.8% and 13.6%.
